# python argparse two subparsers are basically same.. almost

Tags: python, argparse, subparsers

is it possible to extend subparsers new names without implementing all of their parameters twice?
I have a program, let's call it `pgmm` which has a sub function `create`. This create function needs a config file somewhere. To prevent looking for this, create can have the option `--noconfig`.

What I want now is to have some 'pseudo sub parser' maybe like `init`, which is basically the same as `create --noconfig`

I hope that there is a way without implementing the same twice..

is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a way of adding this logic to `argparse` per se, but you don't have to do that to get the behavior you want.  You can create a subparser for `create` and add `init` as an alias for that command so that either command name can be used.  Then, when you consume the arguments after calling `parse_args`, check which subcommand was executed, and if it was `init`, then force the `noconfig` flag to `True`:

```
sub_parsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest="action")

...

sub = sub_parsers.add_parser('create', aliases=['init'])
sub.add_argument('--noconfig', action='store_true')

....

args = parser.parse_args(args)
if args.action == 'init':
    args.noconfig = True
```